# OpenLDAP TLS error: TLS negotiation failure

Tags: openldap

I'm trying to setup OpenLDAP on kubernetes via the helm chart.

It deploys correctly and I am able to access the server over port 389 (unencrypted) both locally from within the container and from other containers like phpldapadmin, in the cluster (via URL: openldap.ldap.svc.cluster.local).

I am not able to access it using tls however. From within the container, if I run this command: `ldapsearch -x -ZZ`, I get this in the logs:

```
5e2e6f05 conn=1035 fd=15 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:44820 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
5e2e6f05 conn=1035 op=0 EXT oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037
5e2e6f05 conn=1035 op=0 STARTTLS
5e2e6f05 conn=1035 op=0 RESULT oid= err=0 text=
TLS: can't accept: (unknown error code).
5e2e6f05 conn=1035 fd=15 closed (TLS negotiation failure)
```

Again, locally from within the openLDAP container itself, if I try `ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://localhost -b "dc=domain,dc=com"` I get:

```
5e2e6a87 conn=1138 fd=15 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:45638 (IP=0.0.0.0:636)
TLS: can't accept: (unknown error code).
5e2e6a87 conn=1138 fd=15 closed (TLS negotiation failure)
```

I don't know what to check next in terms of debugging this. One issue I can see is that in the docker container, it should be run using the `--hostname` parameter but I don't think the helm chart does this and I don't know if I need to set the hostname. Maybe it doesn't like the fact that I am accessing via hostname `localhost` instead of `ldap.domain.com` which is the domain name of the certificate. If that is the case I'm still not sure how to set the hostname to `ldap`, assuming that is what I need to do.

**Environment:**

I installed this chart: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/openldap

which is based on this docker image: https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap

and set the following parameters for the helm chart:

```
existingSecret: openldap-admin-pass
tls.enabled: true
tls.secret: ldap-tls
persistence.enabled: true
persistence.accessMode: ReadWriteMany
persistence.existingClaim: openldap-vol
```

I also changed the config map so that `LDAP_DOMAIN = domain.com`

The certificate itself is generated by cert-manager from let's encrypt. The domain name of the certificate is `ldap.domain.com`. It was signed using DNS validation from cloudflare and is a valid certificate.

The server startup logs to not show any errors, it appears like the TLS configuration and certificates are imported correctly: https://pastebin.com/raw/q9iEZCGN

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I can see in the openLDAP server, the hostname is by default set to the name of the pod: `ldap_int_sasl_open: host=openldap-559644d5d5-l95sg`. Since the pod name changes, I don't know if I need to do something with this to make it match the domain name of the certificate? Or maybe I'm completely off and the solution is something else completely.

Comment: Have you tried `ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap.domain.com -b "dc=domain,dc=com"`?

Comment: Yes, running that command gives this error: `TLS: can't accept: No certificate was found..`. I can confirm that the cert is installed using `echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername ldap.domain.com -connect ldap.domain.com:636 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text` which correctly shows the cert when checking on port 636 as shown here: https://pastebin.com/raw/0ErCGWEp . In the container itself, I can see the certs are correctly placed in `/container/service/slapd/assets/certs`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here:
https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap/issues/105

must set an Environment variable on the openLDAP container: 
LDAP_TLS_VERIFY_CLIENT=try

otherwise it will expect the client to have it's own certificate as well.